# What sort of store does one go to to buy stair parts?

Tags: flooring, stairs, terminology

What sort of store does one go to to buy stair parts?

I want to buy treads, risers, newels, balusters, but Home Depot and Lowe's don't have much of a selection. Are there better types of stores that would carry these parts? Google searches only reveal stair specialists (installers) and I am weary of buying parts online.

I'm in California, it it matters.

Comment: Maybe if you can say more of where you are located, someone might be able to suggest a particular specialty store.  If you are in the middle of nowhere, online is probably your best bet.

Comment: Flooring stores (I used Lumber Liquidators) will have stair treads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [*millwork*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millwork_(building_material)), which is a catch-all term for finished wood products, and includes the stair parts that you mentioned. From Wikipedia:

> **Millwork building materials** are historically any woodmill-produced building construction interior-finish or decorative components. Profiled and patterned millwork building components can usually be installed with minimal alteration. Today, millwork encompasses items that are made using alternatives to wood, such as synthetics, plastics, and wood-adhesive composites.

A lot of them will have the word "millwork" in their company names, and if not, should at least show up in a web search.

If they don't carry the exact pieces that you want, you may find some will be willing to mill items to your specification; this can be useful if you're trying to match hard-to-find trim.

Answer (score 3):

You may still need the internet to find where the various manufacturers of stair parts are sold to the public.

You will need to search for Coffman, LJ Smith. Morgan may not be around anymore, but it may turn up. There are Chinese knock offs of parts that carry the same part numbers, they may turn up in the search also, once you get a look at one of the catalogs to find the parts you want to search for the parts locally perhaps.